# How to Convert String Date in DateTime form in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a string Date which is coming from Database I need to parse or convert that String Date in DateTime form. Sharing the data and code as of now sharing the date which is coming from DB

```
String Date="7/19/2010 7:34:43 AM";

// I am parsing in DateTime form by below code

Date= DateTime.Parse(Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

But I am getting the error while parsing with existing code as **String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.**
Can anyone please share some info how can I resolve this error so that I wont receive any exception

Note

Issue with my code is the date which is coming from Database is not a valid string type that's why I am getting the error string is not recognized as valid datetime

Comment: are you trying this "Date= DateTime.Parse(Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");" in code behind ?

Comment: yes Krunal It is existing code when I debugged I found it is failing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do, using [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx)

```
 DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("7/19/2010 7:34:43 AM",
                            "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",
                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: hi Sajeetharan ,thanks for sharing ur code but when I tried ur code I am getting build error Error 102 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'string'

Comment: @Rahul Try the modified one

Comment: Thanks Sajeetharan now I am not getting error but I don't want to change the variable name I want to use the existing variable only

Comment: @rahul then just replace the variable, your history shows you dont accept answers, try to appreciate those who help you!

Comment: String Date = "7/19/2010 7:34:43 AM";
            Date = DateTime.ParseExact(Date,"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); When I am using I am getting error like cannot convert datetime to system.string and also I am not getting the time details for ex 7 Hours 34 Min 40 Sec AM

Comment: @Rahul yes, replace dt with your varialbe Date

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.ParseExact(yourstring, "yyyyMMdd_HH:mm:ss.fff", new CultureInfo("en-US"));`

Will solve your issue.

For reference follow :

[Date Time Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[Date Time Parse Exact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use

> [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ee1y0t7.aspx) or [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx)

This will allow you to specify specific formats. 
I prefer the TryParseExact as they provide good coding style for the casing error.